# How can I scrape a href that is hidden behind a placeholder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the below href from a site. There are several hrefs on the site which I intend to scrape and so I am looping through the site in order to store them all in one list. Below is an example of one of the hrefs.

```
<div class="col-md-4 h-gutter">
   <div class="product box" data-productid="2111214"> 
      <a href="/products/examples/product1/"> 
         <h3>Product 1</h3> 
         <div class="product-small-text">
```

Here is the section of my code in question. Commented out is my attempt to gather just the hrefs. As this is not working, for now I'm attempting to scrape the entirety of "col-md-4 h-gutter"

```
for product in soup.select('div.product.box'):
    link.append(product)
    #link.append(product.a['href'])

print(link)
```

Below is what is being printed to terminal. As you can see the hrefs are hidden behind a placeholder.

```
</div>, <div class="product placeholder-container box"> 
<h3><span class="placeholder-text--long"></span></h3> 
<div class="product-small-text"> 
<span class="placeholder-text--short"></span> 
</div>
```

How do I print out the value of href?

Comment: Do all relevant `a` hrefs begin with `/products/examples/` ? Maybe it is easier to just search for these instead. Otherwise you'll need to make a more complicated selector.

Comment: @tobias yes they do. However I also need to parse other information at the site which I haven't shown here which makes things difficult. How would be best to search for /products/ in any case?

Comment: `[href*='/products/examples']`   or `[href^='/products/examples']`

Comment: With your initial approach, you can try `.select('.h-gutter > .product .box')`. It is just a CSS selector.

Comment: @tobias unfortunately this just returns a very similar print with the same placeholder values.

Comment: You can write a more explicit selector using `>`

Comment: @QHarr Invalid syntax errors for both

Comment: @tobias this unfortunately does not solve the placeholder issue.

Comment: What is the url? What version of bs4/soupsieve are you using?

Comment: page is dynamically loading through js

Comment: @QHarr anyway to get around this?

Comment: urls come from here `https://www.masterofmalt.com/api/v2/lightningdeals/?isVatableCountry=1&deliveryCountryId=464&filter=nodrams&_=1617024330709` Though some of those param values are probably different depending on where you are and that last unix timestamp can be dropped.

Comment: @QHarr Can I just scape this page instead then?

Comment: yes you can do that. Open network tab of browser with F12 and press F5 to refresh page and then look in network activity for that API call and see what the params are for your locale.

Comment: @QHarr Great, so far so good. How can I pull out certain ```td``` values?

Comment: It's json. Examine the json structure. You should be calling .json() on the response object.

Comment: @QHarr Sorry could you give me a little more context?

```
for product in soup.select('tbl-0'):
   link.append(product(td.json))
```

Something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier to use the json response. If you need it in a table form, just feed that into pandas:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.masterofmalt.com/api/v2/lightningdeals/?isVatableCountry=1&deliveryCountryId=464&filter=nodrams&_=1617024330709&format=json'
headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'}
jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['lightningDeals'])
```

**Output: first 5 rows of 43 rows**

```
print(df.head(5).to_string())
                                                              productUrl                                                                         productImageUrl  productRating  productReviewCount  productVolume  productAbv                categories                   endDateUtc  productId              productName  dealPrice  previousPrice  timeRemaining  saving  percentageClaimed  isActive  dailyDeal
0                      /whiskies/tobermory/tobermory-12-year-old-whisky/                      /whiskies/p-IMAGEPRESET/tobermory/tobermory-12-year-old-whisky.jpg            5.0                  17             70        46.3   [Whiskies, Single Malt]  2021-04-04T22:57:00.0000000      87989    Tobermory 12 Year Old      34.85          39.85         550379     5.0           0.669725      True      False
1  /whiskies/elements-of-islay/peat-pure-islay-elements-of-islay-whisky/  /whiskies/p-IMAGEPRESET/elements-of-islay/peat-pure-islay-elements-of-islay-whisky.jpg            0.0                   0             50        45.0  [Whiskies, Blended Malt]  2021-04-04T22:59:00.0000000      58061          Peat Pure Islay      23.94          28.94         550499     5.0           0.625000      True      False
2                                 /mezcal/ilegal/ilegal-reposado-mezcal/                                 /mezcal/p-IMAGEPRESET/ilegal/ilegal-reposado-mezcal.jpg            5.0                   3             70        40.0        [Mezcal, Reposado]  2021-04-04T22:59:00.0000000       9277          Ilegal Reposado      53.40          59.40         550499     6.0           0.500000      True      False
3                        /whiskies/nikka/nikka-coffey-grain-whisky-70cl/                        /whiskies/p-IMAGEPRESET/nikka/nikka-coffey-grain-whisky-70cl.jpg            4.5                  40             70        45.0         [Whiskies, Grain]  2021-04-04T22:57:00.0000000      32316  Nikka Coffey Grain 70cl      49.83          54.83         550379     5.0           0.410256      True      False
4                              /rum/satchmo/satchmo-mojito-spirited-rum/                              /rum/p-IMAGEPRESET/satchmo/satchmo-mojito-spirited-rum.jpg            5.0                  14             70        37.5             [Rum, Spiced]  2021-04-04T22:58:00.0000000     106576              Satchmo Rum      34.95          39.95         550439     5.0           0.338710      True      False
```

Comment: Sorry, error fixed. How do I pull out just the product Url, dealPrice, saving and store in a list?

Comment: try it with the headers parameter in there

Comment: Fixed, thanks. How do I pull out just the product Url, dealPrice, saving and store in a list? I don't need to store as a table, just these specific parameters in a list (or separate lists).

Comment: use pandas to slice it. Ie `list(df['productUrl'])`.